Где хранить много картинок для сайта на React?
Я зелёный новичок. Разрабатываю pet-проект на React суть которого - большая галерея картинок.
Столкнулся с вопросом, где мне все эти картинки хранить. Неужели нужно каждое изображение добавлять в Redux, и в ручную раскидывать по компонентам? Картинок будет очень много. Или же есть способ сделать это быстрее и проще?
Подскажите пожалуйста, как это правильнее всего реализовать?

Во-первых не изображения а пути к ним («img/app01.jpg») а во-вторых, редакс используется для изменяющихся данных. Для того чтобы Вам дали ответ как сделать лучше, опишите для чего Вы используете эти изображения. Если это товары — это одно, карточная игра — другое, там лучше спрайты использовать, и т.п.

Нет, это обычная галерея с изображениями, просто для просмотра и скачивания.

Смотрите какая штука, обычно галереи редактируют, т.е. к примеру в папку добавляют новые изображения, для того чтобы это сделать грамотно вам нужен бэкэнд, проще говоря сервер который будет возвращать изображения (он сможет находить их у себя на диске) а браузер будет кэшировать. Реакт на сервере — это NextJS, как вариант. Если не хотите сервер, можете сделать json файл где прописать изображения и загружать его через fetch

На backend, советую попробовать Appwrite Storage API. На фронте Redux или любой другой стейт менеджер
import { fetchApi, useAsyncValue } from "react-declarative";

const App = () => {

  const [items] = useAsyncValue(async () => {
    return await fetchApi('/api/v1/images');
  });

  if (!items) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>
  }

  return (
    <>
      {items.map((src) => <img key={src} src={src} />)}
    </>
  )
}




Спасибо большое! Буду изучать!
